# how to get properties and methods of a function?

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects, console.log

> **In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object**
>   Ref: [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

*Therefore, how to get the function methods and properties, as simple objects can caught in `console.log(testObj)`, all the details will goes into the browser console.*
*As it is, how to get the function **object details**.*

**Trying to get function details:**

```
function foo() {
    var a = 2;
    return a;
};

console.log(foo);
```

*Above just returns the signature, `function foo()`.*

**Example: `console.log(document);`**

Comment: I could be wrong, it's just a guess so I'm throwing it in the comments `for(var property in foo) { if(foo.hasOwnProperty(property)) {} }` is how to iterate through the properties of an object if you want to support IE < 9

Comment: Try `console.log('%O', foo);`. The [`%O` formatter](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter) (3.e) should instruct the Console to display the function as a generic object.

Comment: @jonathan-lonowski result is same as above, as you are just passing the arguments in console.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski  `FireFox, version: 53`

Comment: @forweb Firefox doesn't appear to recognize `%O` currently. It does have `console.dir(foo);`, though, which should give equivalent output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`console.dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir) in place of `console.log()`.

```
console.dir(foo);
```

That instructs the Console to display the argument [as a generic object](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#dir), ensuring it's listing with its properties and their values, typically as an expandable tree view.

> 1. Let object be item with [generic JavaScript object formatting](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#generic-javascript-object-formatting) applied.

---

In supporting browsers, the [`%O` formatter](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter) will give the same result.

```
console.log('%O', foo);
```

Comment: i have tried  `console.log( foo.prototype )`, please check and also add it to your answer !

Comment: @forweb That can be helpful if the function is being used as a constructor for other objects, though your question didn't suggest that. Also, the `prototype` will be browsable from `console.dir(foo);`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function has no property.

To get the own enumerable properties, you could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
function foo() {
    var a = 2;
    return a;
};
foo.bar = function (x) { console.log(x); };
foo.baz = 42;

console.log(Object.keys(foo));
console.log(foo.toString());
```

For all properties of `document`, you could use a [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement.

```js
var k;
for (k in document) {
    console.log(k);
}
```

Comment: Note: `Object.keys()` is defined in ES5 and may not be usable in some (albeit very outdated) browsers. Source: [Object.keys() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: @Nina Scholz ,  indeed, but i am trying to get all details in the browser console, as  `console.log(document)` all methods, properties, etc, ... goes there.

Comment: @Nina-Scholz   Well i am not saying how to get properties one by one, i am just asking the behavior of   `console.log(document)` or `console.log(anyObject)`, needs with function objects.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a function as a variable. Javascript gives you the declared whole when being called upon. To get the variable, you need to change the variable declared in the function.
For Example :

```
var a = 2;
function foo(){
    a = 4;
}
console.log(a); //would give you the desired result.
```